# setup.py include custom data file

Tags: python, setuptools

I've written C-based extension module in python. Now I want to create a `setup.py` for installing the library. The library has following folder layout.

```
Mylib
    |--- setup.py
    |--- README.txt
    |--- mylib 
          |--- __init__.py
          |--- core.py
          |--- _core.pyd
```

How can I include `_core.pyd` for the installation? This is the my `setup.py` I tried so far but this does not include my `pyd` file.

```
setup(
    name='mylib',
    version='0.1dev',
    license='GPL',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    packages = find_packages(),
    data_files=[('', ['_core.pyd'])],
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this (if it were in `data` dir)

```
data_files = [('mylib/data', ['mylib/data/_core.pyd']),
              ..others]
```

make sure to include it in `MANIFEST.in` with `include` keyword, like:

```
include mylib/data/*
```

Comment: Thank you, that works :) Why do have the files both, to the setup.py and also to the manifest?